# type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
Future<List> getUsers() async {
  final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('User').get();
  List<String> listFinal = [];
  if (snapshot.value != null) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.value as Map;
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      listFinal.add(value['name']);
    });
    print(listFinal); // ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
  }
  return listFinal;
}
```

```
List<String> listFinal2 = [];

listFinal2 = getUsers() as List<String>;  // I want ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

> type 'Future<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

I want:

```
listFinal2 = listFinal
```

Answer (score 3):

async methods return `Future` instances. If you want the result directly you need to await them. So like

```
listFinal2 = await getUsers();
```

But note that this only can be done inside other async methods. You could alternatively do this when using a non-async method.

```
getUsers().then((value) => listFinal2 = value);
```

But then you need to keep in mind that code below that line are executed before the `then` happens.